# what does | mean when there is no right side in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I saw this in a antlr grammar today but am not sure what it means.  I wish google would let me search for characters...

resultList: (STAR | attributeList |) -> ^(RESULT attributeList? STAR?);

Notice the second "|" character has no right side element?  What does that mean?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means it matches nothing. The following, slightly more verbose rule, does exactly the same:

```
resultList
 : STAR          -> ^(RESULT STAR)
 | attributeList -> ^(RESULT attributeList)
 | /* nothing */ -> RESULT
 ;
```

I think the version above is more clear, and will also be easier to evaluate later on sine there are no two optional child nodes, `attributeList` and `STAR`, you need to check for their presence.